# How can I change a Bootstrap 5 tooltip color based on button style?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I need some help I want to change the tooltip `background-color` based on button main color.

for example: if the button has `background-color` **"primary"** the tooltip `background-color` should be **"primary"** too...

**HTML:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Primary">Primary</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Secondary">Secondary</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Success">Success</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Danger">Danger</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Warning">Warning</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-info" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Info">Info</button>
```

**jQuery:**

```
(function (window, document, $, undefined) {
    var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'));
    var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
        return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl);
    });

    $(".btn-primary").hover(function () {
        $(".tooltip-inner").css({ "background-color": "var(--bs-primary)" });
    });

    $(".btn-danger").hover(function () {
        $(".tooltip-inner").css({ "background-color": "var(--bs-danger)" });
    });
})(window, document, jQuery);
```

**Live Example:** https://codepen.io/themes4all/pen/NWabvad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it dynamic using `dataset`.

In javascript you just need to add `hover` on `button` and in handler add dynamic color based on the dataset value.

```
    $("button").hover(function () {
        $(".tooltip-inner").css({ "background-color": "var(--bs-" + $(this).data("color") + ")" });
        $(".tooltip-arrow").css({ "background-color": "var(--bs-" + $(this).data("color") + ")" });
    });
```

See the Snippet below:

```js
(function (window, document, $, undefined) {
    var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'));
    var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
        return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl);
    });

    $("button").hover(function () {
        $(".tooltip-inner").css({ "background-color": "var(--bs-" + $(this).data("color") + ")" });
    });
})(window, document, jQuery);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous" />

        <title>Bootstrap</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container mt-5">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-color="primary" data-bs-placement="top" title="Primary">Primary</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Secondary" data-color="secondary">Secondary</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Success" data-color="success">Success</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Danger" data-color="danger">Danger</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Warning" data-color="warning">Warning</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-info" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Info" data-color="info">Info</button>

        </div>
        
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

See the [Codepen here](https://codepen.io/nimittshah/pen/oNGBqoG).

Comment: How I can change the arrow color too ?

Answer (score 0):

### You get a data attribute, and *you* get a data attribute!

Since tooltip arrows are pseudo-elements we can't directly style them with CSS. We can use CSS to style them based on their parent elements, though. And since we can't easily remove classes when the color changes, we'll use a data attribute that we can simply overwrite. Building on Nimitt Shah's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70351128/1264804) to use a data attribute for color, we'll do so.

You may be able to substitute color variables for the hard-coded colors I've used here.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'));
  var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function(tooltipTriggerEl) {
    return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl);
  });

  $("button").hover(function() {
    $(".tooltip").attr('data-color', $(this).data("color"));
  });
});
```

```css
.tooltip[data-color=primary] .tooltip-inner {
  background-color: #0d6efd;
}

.tooltip[data-color=primary] .tooltip-arrow:before {
  border-top-color: #0d6efd;
}

.tooltip[data-color=secondary] .tooltip-inner {
  background-color: #6c757d;
}

.tooltip[data-color=secondary] .tooltip-arrow:before {
  border-top-color: #6c757d;
}

.tooltip[data-color=success] .tooltip-inner {
  background-color: #198754;
}

.tooltip[data-color=success] .tooltip-arrow:before {
  border-top-color: #198754;
}

.tooltip[data-color=danger] .tooltip-inner {
  background-color: #dc3545;
}

.tooltip[data-color=danger] .tooltip-arrow:before {
  border-top-color: #dc3545;
}

.tooltip[data-color=warning] .tooltip-inner {
  background-color: #ffc107;
  color: #000;
}

.tooltip[data-color=warning] .tooltip-arrow:before {
  border-top-color: #ffc107;
}

.tooltip[data-color=info] .tooltip-inner {
  background-color: #0dcaf0;
  color: #000;
}

.tooltip[data-color=info] .tooltip-arrow:before {
  border-top-color: #0dcaf0;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container mt-5">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-color="primary" data-bs-placement="top" title="Primary">Primary</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Secondary" data-color="secondary">Secondary</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Success" data-color="success">Success</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Danger" data-color="danger">Danger</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Warning" data-color="warning">Warning</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-info" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Info" data-color="info">Info</button>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
```